# lxml: Copy-and-Rename a bunch of Elements

Tags: python, xslt, lxml

I have an input file looking like this:

```
<article>
 <pages>
   <list-item>content of page 1</list-item>
   <list-item>content of page 2</list-item>
   <list-item>content of page 3</list-item>
 </pages>
</article>
```

I want to transform it into another XML file looking like

```
<text>
  <page>content of page 1</page>
  <page>content of page 2</page>
  <page>content of page 3</page>
</text>
```

The following ugly piece of code does what I want to achieve:

```
oldtree = etree.parse(infile)
newtree = etree.Element("text")
newtree.append(oldtree.find("pages"))
outfile.write(etree.tostring(newtree).replace(u"<pages>", u"").replace(u"</pages>",u"").replace(u"<list-item>", u"<page>").replace("</list-item>", u"</page>"))
```

The ugly part is the mix-up of XML transformations with brute force replacements. Is there are more pure and beautifull way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You have tagged this XSLT, but you are not using it for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring, tostring

text_tree = """
<article>
 <pages>
   <list-item>content of page 1</list-item>
   <list-item>content of page 2</list-item>
   <list-item>content of page 3</list-item>
 </pages>
</article>
"""

pages = fromstring(text_tree).find('pages')
pages.tag = 'text'
for list_item in pages.findall('list-item'):
    list_item.tag = 'page'

print tostring(pages)
```

Will give:

```
<text>
   <page>content of page 1</page>
   <page>content of page 2</page>
   <page>content of page 3</page>
 </text>
```